# Scale images as a single surface in Java 2D API

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, 2d

There is a method called `scale(double sx, double sy)` in `Graphics2D` in Java. But this method seems like to scale images as ***separate surfaces*** rather than a ***single surface***. As a result, scaled images have ***sharp corners*** if original images have no extra width and height. The following screenshot demonstrates the problem:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestJava {
    static int scale = 10;

    public static class Test extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.scale(scale, scale);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("Sprite.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g2.drawImage(img, null, 5, 5);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Test test = new Test();
        test.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.add(test);
        frame.setSize(300, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

One possible solution to the problem is original images having extra width and height (in this case `"Sprite.png"`). But this does not seem to be a good way to eliminate the problem. So I am seeking for a programmatic way in Java to solve this problem rather than using an image editor. What is the way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting question (+1). I think that it is not trivial to find a *good* solution for this: The interpolation when scaling up the image always happens **inside** the image, and I can not imagine a way to make it blur the scaled pixels **outside** the image.

This leads to fairly simple solution: One could add a 1-pixel-margin around the whole image. In fact, this **is** the programmatic way of the solution that you proposed yourself. The resuld would look like this:

[image: ScaledImage]

(the left one is the original, and the right one has the additional 1-pixel-border)

Here as a MCVE, based on your example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ScaledPaint
{
    static int scale = 10;

    public static class Test extends JPanel
    {
        BufferedImage image = createTestImage();
        BufferedImage imageWithMargin = addMargin(image);

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.scale(scale, scale);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

            g2.drawImage(image, 5, 5, null);
            g2.drawImage(imageWithMargin, 30, 5, null);
        }
    }

    private static BufferedImage createTestImage()
    {
        BufferedImage image =
            new BufferedImage(20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 19, 19);
        g.dispose();
        return image;
    }

    private static BufferedImage addMargin(BufferedImage image)
    {
        return addMargin(image, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    }

    private static BufferedImage addMargin(BufferedImage image, 
        int left, int right, int top, int bottom)
    {
        BufferedImage newImage =
            new BufferedImage(
                image.getWidth() + left + right,
                image.getHeight() + top + bottom, 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, left, top, null);
        g.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }

    private static BufferedImage convertToARGB(BufferedImage image)
    {
        BufferedImage newImage =
            new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Test test = new Test();
        test.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.add(test);
        frame.setSize(600, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### But...

... one problem with this approach can already be seen in the screenshot: The image becomes larger. And you'll have to take this into account when painting the image. So if your original sprites all had a nice, predefined, easy-to-handle size like 16x32, they will afterwards have a size of 18x34, which is rather odd for a tile. This may not a problem, depending on how you are handling your tile sizes. But if it is a problem, one could think about possible solutions. One solution might be to ...

- take the 16x32 input image
- create a 16x32 output image
- paint the 16x32 intput image into the region (1,1)-(15,31) of the output image

But considering the fact that in sprites of this size, **every single pixel** may be important, this may have undesirable effects as well...

---

An aside: Altough I assume that the code that you posted was only intended as a MCVE, I'd like to point out (for others who might read this question and the code) :

- You shoud **NOT** load images in the `paintComponent` method
- For efficient painting, any PNG that is loaded (particularly when it contains transparency) should be converted into an image with a known type. This can be done with the `convertToARGB` method in my code snippet.

Comment: I've created a function `drawImage(Graphics2D g, BufferedImage img, int x, int y)` that does `g.drawImage(imageWithMargin, x - 1, y - 1, null)`. And it works as expected! But it would be better if there's a way that can scale up images by treating them as one image. I mean: 1. Draw all images unscaled in an image surface; 2. Scale the image surface; 3. Draw the image surface to a display device.

Comment: @arnobpl Drawing at (x-1,y-1) is a nice and simple solution, assuming that the actual size does not matter. (And that's what SHE said...). It would probably also be possible to draw all images with their original size into another, large `BufferedImage` (with a size of (screenSizeX/10,screenSizeY/10), and then draw this image on the screen (with a graphics that is scaled by (10,10)). But this may also be a bit fiddly, and it's hard to say whether this has potential drawbacks for your application case. (It should not affect performance too much, but one has to think about how well it may work)

Answer (score 4):

In your example it's not the image you scale, but you set a scaling transformation on the `Graphics2D` object which will be applied on all operations performed on that graphics context.

If you want to scale an image, you have 2 options. All I write below uses `java.awt.Image`, but since `BufferedImage` extends `Image`, all this applies to `BufferedImage` as well.

### 1. `Image.getScaledInstance()`

You can use the `Image.getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)` method. The 3rd parameter (the `hints`) tells what scaling algorithm you want to use which will affect the "quality" of the scaled image. Possible values are:

```
SCALE_DEFAULT, SCALE_FAST, SCALE_SMOOTH, SCALE_REPLICATE, SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING
```

Try the `SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING` and the `SCALE_SMOOTH` for nicer scaled images.

```
// Scaled 3 times:
Image img2 = img.getScaledInstance(img.getWidth(null)*3, img.getHeight(null)*3,
    Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);
// Tip: you should cache the scaled image and not scale it in the paint() method!

// To draw it at x=100, y=200
g2.drawImage(img2, 100, 200, null);
```

### 2. `Graphics.drawImage()`

You can use different `Graphics.drawImage()` overloads where you can specify the size of the scaled image. You can "control" the image quality with the `KEY_INTERPOLATION` rendering hint. It has 3 possible values:

```
VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR, VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR,
VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC
```

The `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR` uses a bilinear interpolation algorithm of the 4 nearest pixels. The `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC` uses a cubic interpolation of the 9 nearby pixels.

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

// To draw image scaled 3 times, x=100, y=200:
g2.drawImage(img, 100, 200, img.getWidth(null)*3, img.getHeight(null)*3, null);
```

### Removing sharp edges

If you want to avoid sharp edges around the image, you should write a loop to go over the pixels at the edge of the image, and set some kind of transparency, e.g. alpha=0.5 (or alpha=128). You might also do this on multiple rows/columns, e.g. 0.8 alpha for the edge, 0.5 alpha for the 2nd line and 0.3 alpha for the 3rd line.

Comment: An excellent answer, but - if I understood this correctly - not for this question ;-)